# calculating accuracy and precision for multiclass system

Tags: statistics, classification

I'm currently evaluating a bag of words texture classifier which output binary results:

- true positives(**TP**)
- true negatives(**TN**)
- false positives(**FP**)
- false negatives(**FN**)

I'm looking to calculate the accuracy but am not sure i'm assigning true negatives correctly.

I'm currently working with 8 classes and assign 7 true negatives each time there is a true positive, and 6 true negatives and a false negative each time there is a false positive.

I wasn't sure if i should instead add one to the true negatives only when there is a true positive?
This still seems to give overly high results, like for these results:

**TP**: 20

**FP**: 10

**TN**: 20

**FN**: 10

**Accuracy**: 0.66

when assigning true negatives like i originally did it's even higher. Shouldn't accuracy be 50% when only half the results are correct or is this normal?

Also do you think this is the best metric to measure classifier accuracy or is there something more advanced?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i've read the method i was using at first was correct, although standard Accuracy (Overall Accuracy) is not necessarily the best way to evaluate a classifier.

Precision and Recall are the widely used as they represent both type 1 and type 2 errors. For a single combined metric however then the F1Measure is typically used [F1Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) this is the Harmonic mean of precision and recall and can be calculated with this formula:
[formula](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?F=&space;2&space;*&space;%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Ctextrm%7BRecall%7D%7D*%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Ctextrm%7BPrecision%7D%7D%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Ctextrm%7BRecall%7D%7D+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Ctextrm%7BPrecision%7D%7D%7D).

Other options such as ROC curves(generated from the True Positive Rate(TPR) and False Positive Rate(FPR)), are also used although not necessarily for multi class systems. To generate a single metric with these the Area Under the Curve(AUC) is taken which largely represents the classifier's predictive ability. This is again however not widely used for multiclass systems.